# Which parameters and metrics to look at when CDC based replication is causing high load?

Tags: oracle, change-data-capture, tungsten-replicator

I'm investigating the reasons why a Tungsten Replicator extractor is causing heavy load on an Oracle 11g database. The replication is set up to use synchronous CDC and there is no unusual load while the extractor is *not* running, which leads me to believe that the triggers registered by the CDC package are working just fine, without causing any significant load.

When the extractor *is* running, the load average of the database server can go as high as 60, but it's not that high all the time. Most likely the variance depends on the number of writes.

What configuration parameters and/or metrics of the database should I look into to identify the cause of this load? Tungsten seems to be simply running standard CDC procedures as outlined below.

Initial prepartion steps of the extractor:

1. Get a list of tables to extract from a table prepared by a setup script:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM TUNGSTEN_SOURCE_TABLES
   ```
2. For each source table, get a list of columns to extract.

   ```
   SELECT
     UNIQUE CHANGE_SET_NAME,
     PUB.COLUMN_NAME,
     PUB_ID,
     COL.COLUMN_ID
   FROM TUNGSTEN_PUBLISHED_COLUMNS PUB, ALL_TAB_COLUMNS COL
   WHERE
     SOURCE_SCHEMA_NAME = '{SERVICE_NAME}' AND
     SOURCE_TABLE_NAME = '{TABLE_NAME}' AND
     SOURCE_SCHEMA_NAME = COL.OWNER AND
     SOURCE_TABLE_NAME = COL.TABLE_NAME AND
     PUB.COLUMN_NAME = COL.COLUMN_NAME AND
     CHANGE_SET_NAME = 'TUNGSTEN_CS_{SERVICE_NAME}'
   ORDER BY COL.COLUMN_ID
   ```
3. Create a subscription with `DBMS_CDC_SUBSCRIBE.CREATE_SUBSCRIPTION`
4. Create a subscriber view for each source table with `DBMS_CDC_SUBSCRIBE.SUBSCRIBE`
5. Activate the subscription with `DBMS_CDC_SUBSCRIBE.ACTIVATE_SUBSCRIPTION`

Inner loop of the extractor while it's running:

1. Extend the subscription window with `DBMS_CDC_SUBSCRIBE.EXTEND_WINDOW`
2. Select each subscription view to fetch any changes

   ```
   -- Receiving changes for the first time
   SELECT
     COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ...,
     CSCN$,
     COMMIT_TIMESTAMP$,
     OPERATION$
   FROM VW_TUNGSTEN_{SERVICE_NAME}{INDEX}
   ORDER BY CSCN$, RSID$

   -- Receiving changes after the first window
   SELECT
     COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ...,
     CSCN$,
     COMMIT_TIMESTAMP$,
     OPERATION$
   FROM VW_TUNGSTEN_{SERVICE_NAME}{INDEX}
   WHERE CSCN$ > :lastSCN
   ORDER BY CSCN$, RSID$
   ```
3. Purge the subscription window with `DBMS_CDC_SUBSCRIBE.PURGE_WINDOW`

Environment:

- Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production

  - According to my client, this box is 5 years old
  - open_mode: read write
  - log_mode: archivelog
  - platform_id: 10
  - platform_name: Linux IA (32-bit)
- Tungsten Replicator 3.0.0

Comment: Do you know how to generate and analyse AWR reports?

Comment: No, I have no experience with AWR. Since the database in question is not under the Enterprise license, it's not equipped to generate reports, as far as I understand. I suppose I'll need to query the relevant tables directly. Thanks, and any further pointers still appreciated.

Comment: *query the relevant tables directly*: It looks like this is not allowed unless you have purchased the [Diagnostics Pack](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/license.111/b28287/options.htm#DBLIC164).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to tune up the Oracle side of parameters, due to having limited access to the database instance, but the database load has seen improvements after stripping down the tables and columns that are being replicated.

#### 1. Determine which tables are getting updated the most.

Try running the extractor for a few hours and let the THL grow. Then, you can count the number of changes logged for each table using a command like:

```
./bin/thl list | gawk -f thl_summary.awk | sort -n -r
```

Where `thl_summary.awk` is:

```
#!/bin/gawk
# Sum up rows from a `bin/thl list` output
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
}
match($0, /- TABLE = (.*)/, a) {
    table=a[1]
}
match($0, /- ROW# = (.*)/, a) {
    rows[table]++
}
END {
    for (k in rows) {
        print rows[k], k
    }
}
```

#### 2. Replicate only those tables and columns that are necessary.

Looking at the list of tables, ask yourself if you can exclude any of them.

- Exclude `CLOB` columns.

  - They aren't really supported by synchronous CDC.
  - Even if you specify a subset of the columns in `DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH.CREATE_CHANGE_TABLE`, each and every change will be logged to the change table<sup>1</sup>. But by excluding `CLOB` columns, we can lessen the load of costly writes and reads.
- Exclude all tables that are not really needed on the downstream database.

  - If necessary, add a fallback table with a subset of the columns that you really need, even if it means denormalizing a bit.
  - The way Tungsten configures CDC, a single update to a source row generates two rows in the corresponding change table<sup>2</sup>. These extra updates can add up if you have a frequently updated table.

Once you've determined which tables and columns to replicate, you can specify them  in a file named `tungsten.tables`:

```
aSubsetOfTheTable<TAB>column1,...,columnN
wholeTable
```

Then, you need to re-run the `setupCDC.sh` script with `setupCDC.conf`:

```
specific_tables=1
```

---

<sup>1</sup> https://community.oracle.com/thread/2288254

<sup>2</sup> *Updated rows will generate a record with operation$='UU' ... and all the old values, and another record with operation$='UN' or 'UL' with new values.* ([source](http://www.bikinfo.com/HTML/CDC/CDC_Article.html))